# upgrading Ruby on Openshift (Python Cartridge)

Tags: python, ruby, openshift, iron.io

I'm working on a Flask app + deploying to RedHat OpenShift using the Python 2.7 cartridge. I need to use some ruby CLI tools to create & upload Iron.io Workers, but the CLI tool requires Ruby 1.9.2 and the cart only has Ruby 1.8.7.

I can't install rvm / rbenv via sshing into the gear, because OpenShift won't give you root access. So, is there a way to install Ruby on OpenShift without sudo or am I SOL?

*(Somebody at Iron.io suggested using Iron.io via Docker, but that seems like overkill for scheduling SMS texts.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't update your ruby cartridge on openshift. You will have to make a new app and use ruby 1.9 from very beginning. You can use something like:

```
rhc app create myapp ruby-1.9
```

Comment: so I can't run up-to-date versions of Python & Ruby concurrently -- unless RedHat updates their carts? That's kind of balls. But thanks!

Comment: you can use them concurrently. my code was installing ruby 1.9 cart only. just decide which carts and version you will need before you make app on openshift and write them in one line.

Comment: if you want to add a cartidge of python to an app which already has ruby 1.9 then you use `rhc cartridge add -a myapp python-2.7`.  you might https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-common-rhc-commands.html useful.

Comment: This does not work. I want to install a newer python and pip in my OpenShift Rails app but I get: "There are no cartridges that match 'python-2.7'.".